# Why isn't PHP displaying errors under IIS7?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, error-reporting

I get a blank white page when running a script that I'm migrating from a Linux Apache server to IIS.

Following advice elsewhere on SO, I checked that the correct `php.ini` is being loaded. From `phpinfo()`:

> **Loaded Configuration File** C:\php\php.ini

In that `php.ini` file, I have the following:

- `error_reporting = E_ALL`
- `display_errors = On`
- `log_errors = On`
- `error_log = "C:\Windows\Temp\php_errors.log"`

For good measure, I have also added

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

in the script itself.

I'm getting no errors output to the screen, and the file `C:\Windows\Temp\php_errors.log` doesn't exist.

I'm obviously missing something; what is it? :)

Comment: Can it be related to a web.config file? I usually working with linux servers but I remember one case that someone told me something about web.config file.

Comment: @OfirBaruch: The site in question does use a web.config file, but it doesn't make any reference to error reporting.